# Handle Thread/Greenlit kill in gevent

Tags: python, multithreading, gevent

I wish to create a non-blocking thread/Greenlit in gevent. The thread is meant to run until some kind of signal is sent to stop it, at which point I wish to perform an action (save some data).

From the gevent kill [docs](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.Greenlet.kill) I would expect the following code to print `Done` upon being killed:

```
import gevent
def myloop():
    try:
        while True:
            pass
    except gevent.greenlet.GreenletExit:
        print "Done"
thread = gevent.spawn(myloop)
thread.kill()
```

However, that doesn't happen. Any ideas as to why? Am I doing something horribly wrong? How can I achieve the specified behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your greenlet is never actually "blocking", but consuming CPU forever, it's never killed. From gevent's point of view, it's going to be killed, but this will never happen because the greenlet will never leave its while-loop.

I'm pretty sure that if you add `sleep(0)` in your while loop, `sleep` will raise GreenletExit and the loop will break.

In fact, you can deduce this by looking at your code :

```
try:
    while True:
        pass
except ...:
    ...
```

There is syntaxically nothing that can raise an exception here. We need to do something that can raise, and that's `sleep(0)`.

Comment: Btw, killing a greenlet right after spawning it may cause it never gets scheduled. Try add `gevent.sleep(0)` before `thread.kill()` then the message should be shown correctly.

Comment: In fact, if he adds `gevent.sleep(0)` before `thread.kill()`, the behaviour I described happens : it deadlocks, consuming CPU time forever. This is because gevent has no way to patch anything in `while True: pass`.

Comment: Additional note: gevent hides the difference between normal functions calls and context switches, and this is maybe why the original poster got confused. `gevent.sleep(0)` is not a "normal function call", it will actually yield to the event loop, something which `pass` doesn't. In other languages such as Node.JS, every function call yields to the event loop, so maybe such code would be able terminate.

Comment: Replacing `pass` with `gevent.sleep(0)` and also inserting it before `thread.kill()` achieves exactly what I wanted, thanks!